# Can't SSH to EC2 specific port

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm would like to open an SSH connection between my local machine and an EC2 instance.

I added my local IP (static) with this port to the 'Groups Permissions' but it doesn't work yet.

When I do:
`ssh -i .ssh/my_key.pem ubuntu@server_ip -p 8867`
It's telling me `ssh: connect to host <server_ip> port 8867: Connection refused`.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Is your EC2 instance definitely listening on that port?

Comment: No it's not (see answer below). I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the server is listening on port 8867 using netstat

```
netatat -tunlp | grep 8867
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8867       0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      1425/sshd
```

If it's not then take the necessary steps to start it. 
If it is listening then you may need to open port 8867 on the Ubuntu firewall.

---

Update based on the comments

To have sshd listen on port 8867 you will need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add a `Port` statement.

```
Port 8867
```

Note that sshd will listen on port 22 by default so if you want sshd to listen on port 8867 as well as port then you need 2 Port statements.

```
Port 22
Port 8867
```

You should probably take a look at the documentation too [sshd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) and [sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).

Comment: netstat is not showing my port. How do I tell my server to listen to it?

Comment: @GuilhemSoulas: see my update.

Comment: Thanks @lain it worked! It may look like a stupid question but everyone has to start from the beginning.

Comment: @GuilhemSoulas: You didn't start at the beginning - you jumped right in but forgot about reading documentation ;).